# Norm of orthonormal basis

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces

I know that an orthonormal basis of a vector space, say V is a orthogonal basis in which each entry has unit length.

My question is, then, if you have some orthonormal basis say $\{v_1,\ldots,v_8\}$ for example, and you want to calculate the norm of some $v* \in V$, say $v*=v_1+5v_2-6v_3+v_4$

Does it suffice to just calculate this as $1+5-6+1$ for example. Or is there some other aspect I should be considering?

Thank you

Comment: no, it would be $\sqrt{1^2 + 5^2 + (-6)^2 + 1^2}$

Comment: Oh, I see that makes sense. I think that is where I was confused about the factors in front of the vectors. For example, I thought it might make sense to also calcuate the norms separately and add them but that would not work because we would get $\sqrt{1}+\sqrt{25}-\sqrt{36}+\sqrt{1}$ but this would not be the same as square rooting them all under the same square root right?

Comment: That is correct; it is **not** generally true that $\sqrt{a + b} = \sqrt a + \sqrt b$. (and so in particular, $\sqrt{x^2 + y^2} \neq \sqrt{ x^2} + \sqrt{y^2} = x + y$). If you get into trouble with stuff like this, try examples with actual numbers. Are $\sqrt{25 + 36}$ and $\sqrt{25} + \sqrt{36}$ the same number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $x = \sum_i a_i v_i$ where $\{v_i\}$ form an orthonormal basis, $||x|| = \sqrt{\sum_i |a_i|^2}$. This is just Pythagorean theorem.